# IDEA: Resource registered by this uri is not recognized (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs)

Tags: intellij-idea, cxf

xmlns:http-conf="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
IDEA got error:
Resource registered by this uri is not recognized (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fM1GE.png)